# Запускать задачу по полю DateTime модели

Tags: python, python-3.9, scheduler

Заголовок вопроса очень размыт. Мне не удалось грамотно его сформулировать.

Есть задача, заключающаяся в том, чтобы реализовать модель Task, имеющую поле deadline. Когда текущее время равно значению поля deadline экземпляра Task, необходимо его обрабатывать соответствующим образом. Например, установить статус failed.

Мое решение:
в бесконечном цикле какого-либо слоя бизнес-логики фильтровать экземпляры Task (deadline__lte=datetime.now()), а затем передавать все эти экземпляры на обработку.

Возможно, что мое решение вполне подходит, но я полагаю, есть более изящный вариант.

В качестве БД используется PostgreSQL, в качестве ORM - tortoise.

Comment: а не проще обойтись без цикла и просто проверять время при обращении к экземпляру?

Comment: @strawdog а что, если я хочу уведомить пользователя о том, что его задача задедлайнилась? Или проработать еще ряд подобных ситуаций? Или я Вас неправильно понял? Я планирую, что механизм будет автономным.

Comment: ну вот как вы решили уведомить пользователя - проверяйте экземпляр.

Comment: @strawdog а как я пойму, что пора уведомить пользователя?

Comment: @strawdog процессы, которые происходят при наступлении времени напрямую зависят от времени, определенном в поле DateTime экземпляра.